# MySQL - I have an issue with blank space

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a drop down list on a form with values:

```
Value One
Value Two
Value Three
```

The values go into a db.

I have another db with columns

```
Value One
Value Two
Value Three
```

I have an IF statement that if form Value One to get records in db from Colum Value One.

But getting error message Unknown column 'Value' in 'field list'

I think it has to do with the space? Can I have spaces in the names in MYSQL? If I change it to Value_One, Value_Two, Value_Three can I change the form input Value to be Value%One, Value%Two, Value%Three etc will that work? Ideas?

Comment: if you know the field really exist, surround it with the left quotes \`

Comment: also if these are strings surround them with quotes

Comment: So make the form value <option value='Value One'>Value One</option>???

Comment: @user718359 post your php code here for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap column names, table names, and other identifiers that contain spaces or keywords (like "select") with [**backticks**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

```
`Value One`
```

However, from the sound of it, I'm not sure that is your only issue. A use case where you select a column name in a form and submit it is a strange one.

Is it possible that you are trying to get the **values** from a single column of the database, instead of multiple *columns*?

Use `DESC tablename` to find out the column names.

Comment: Just tried and renamed the column to `Value One`.. Still getting Unknown column 'Value' in 'field list'

Comment: If you put backticks around "Value One" then it would not still be saying "Unknown column 'Value'" -- though, it might be saying "Unknown column 'Value One'"

Comment: If I rename the form value Value_One and the colum in the db Value_One it all works perfectly???

Comment: The only thing is that the vlaue then becomes Value_One and when I want it to ech etc as Value One

Comment: @user718359 That's one solution.  As I said... backticks are your friend, too.  Side note:  You should not be using *column names* in this way, especially not submitting them as form values or echoing them.

Comment: @user718359 You haven't given us enough information about what you are actually trying to accomplish to help.  Post a new question with more information about the goal of this code, *especially code samples*

Comment: Basically the form value gets inserted into one db and then I say IF form value = culumn name pull certain records.. but the space is causing problems..

Answer (score 1):

It's always a little harder to debug without seeing your code -- the offending SQL statement for example -- but you might benefit from referring to the column as `Value One` (note the backtick quote marks).

**Update: response to comment**

This works for me:

```
INSERT INTO `test_db` ( `Value One` ) VALUES ( 'Test data' );
```

Comment: The only thing is that the vlaue then becomes Value_One and when I want it to ech etc as Value One